# MBProgressHUD is not shown on time when main thread is blocked

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, cocos2d-x, mbprogresshud

I'm developing a game that uses cocos2d-x, I'm having a problem on old devices such as ipad 1 where large scene takes a lot of time to load.
so the scene transition can take a few seconds, therefore I tried to implement a "busy" animation between scene transitions while the new scene is being loaded.
I implemented this using MBProgressHUD on IOS and ProgressDialog on android.
I decided that I don't want to start showing this animation immediately, instead I could schedule the animation to start 1-2 seconds after the scene transition starts, so that on newer devices the animation will not be shown at all.
Initially what I did was this:

```
- (void) showProgressDialog: (int) runWithoutDelay
    {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showProgressDialogAfterDelay) object:nil];
    shouldShow = YES;
    if (runWithoutDelay){
        [self showProgressDialogAfterDelay];
    }
   else{
       [self performSelector:@selector(showProgressDialogAfterDelay) withObject:nil   afterDelay:delay];
       }
   }

- (void) showProgressDialogAfterDelay
  {
   if (shouldShow){
       isShown = YES;
       [progressHUD show:YES];
   }

}
```

and if I pass the scene transition part I would just set shouldShow flag to false and won't start the animation.
The problem is that because cocos2d-x scene transition is done in main\ui thread sometimes instead of calling the show method after 2 seconds it takes up to 6-8 seconds for it to be called and sometimes it even gets called after I set my flag to false.
As I understand it happens because performSelector (and so is NSTimer which I also tried) both run on the same thread by placing the call in the thread run loop queue.
I needed something like performSelectorInBackground that takes delay, so I tried using dispatch_after (even though I still haven't figure out how this could be canceled, as I need to cancel a previous schedule when I create a new one) this looked more accurate according Xcode's logs but even though the logs said that the method was called exactly 2 seconds after being scheduled the time would take 5-8 seconds to show and sometimes would not show at all.
As I understand it, and correct me if I'm wrong, this happens because MBProgressHUD changes to UI must happen on main\UI thread so even though I call [ProgressHUD show:YES] on a background thread the actual update of the UI is scheduled to be executed somehow on the main thread and because of it being stuck on cocos2d-x stuff it only starts to show after that, when the scene transition is completed and its too late.

is there any way around this problem? can I somehow schedule it to start with a delay but have it display right when I want it?

What I don't understand is why if I start it with no delay the animation works smoothly without being stuck even though the main thread is busy with cocos2d-x processing.

Comment: the problem isn't the UI here, it's that the resource loading (or whatever takes so long) runs on the main thread and thus blocking it. In cocos2d-iphone for instance you have several "async" methods that load textures and sprite frames in the background to allow a foreground loading animation to play. That's what you need to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. I know that the main issue is that I have a lot of non-UI stuff running on the UI thread, I tried to be simplistic when I wrote my question, the platform I'm running is quite big and wasn't written by me and it would be impossible to do this change in the time frame I have to deal with this issue. so currently this isn't an option, is there anyway I can deal with it on a different way? i.e changing the progress dialog code somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I‘ve managed a way around this somehow!

1. Create a normal method where you will call the progressHUD and call the second
2. Create the second method where you do the time consuming stuff (loading views)
3. Perform that method on the main thread

Sample:

```
-(void)callHUD {

            [progressHUD show];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [progressHUD dismiss];
    });
});
}

-(void)loadView {
    //Perform your segue or transition which needs to load
}
```

Hope that could help you a little.

Comment: I know longer work there, but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Thought maybe the next person with the issue comes across this post! :) I had this issue myself and worked out my own piece of code for this.